# How to configure or set cookie as json before making a post request in locust load test tool for FastHTTPUser

Tags: python-3.x, locust

Locust is having option to use HTTPUser and FastHTTPUser
HTTPUSer internally using python requests which accepts cookies as an argument with json content
e.g. self.client.get(url, header=myheader, cookies=mycookies) here I can configure mycookies as json. Same is not working if I change the code to FastHTTPUser instead of HTTPUser. Need details how to configure hardcoded cookies as key value before making the request in FastHTTPUser approach.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you have received downvotes for your question. I found it valid and I think you should create an issue in the locust github page:
https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/

I think you could solve it like this:

```py
from requests.cookies import cookiejar_from_dict

@task
def task_cookie(self):
    cookiejar_from_dict(mycookies, self.client.cookiejar)
    self.client.get(url, header=myheader)
```

I will try to make a PR to make this automatic