# How to share cookie for all request for an user in locust?

Tags: locust

I'd like to share the `_profiler` cookie for all request for an user, anyway to do this in locust?

```
 self.client.post(
    "/customer/account/loginPost/bind/no/",
    headers = headers, 
    data = {
        'login[username]': email, 
        'login[password]': password, 
        'form_key': form_key
    },
    cookies={
        '_profiler': True
    }
)

//Another request in another task, I hope the `_profiler` cookies exists here.
self.client.get('/customer/section/load?sections=cart&force_new_section_timestamp=false',headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's related to this:

[How to configure or set cookie as json before making a post request in locust load test tool for FastHTTPUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217160/how-to-configure-or-set-cookie-as-json-before-making-a-post-request-in-locust-lo/65251359#65251359)

You could use the same approach